# Evaluate $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sin x\cos x}{\sin^4x+\cos^4x}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> Evaluate
>   $$
> \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sin(x)\cos(x)}{\sin^4(x)+\cos^4(x)}dx
> $$

I used the substitution $\sin x =t$, then I got the integral as $$\int_0^1 \frac{t}{2t^4-2t^2+1}dt $$

After that I don't know how to proceed. Please help me with this.

Comment: You see how the equation looks very ugly right now? The answer to this problem is typesetting it with MathJax. I would strongly recommend using it.

Comment: I am new here, I will start using from the next question. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like a substitution $u=t^2$ is called for. But your next question; why not edit this one using MathJax?

Comment: Thanks. I got the final answer as π /4. is it correct? @LordSharktheUnknown

Comment: PARI/GP approves the result numerically, so you apparently got it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Putnam definite integral evaluation $\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{x\sin x\cos x}{\sin^4 x+\cos^4 x}dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1072316/putnam-definite-integral-evaluation-int-0-pi-2-fracx-sin-x-cos-x-sin4-x)

Answer (score 5):

Do  some trigonometry first:
\begin{align}
\frac{\sin x\cos x}{\sin^4x+\cos^4x}&=\frac{\tfrac12\sin 2x}{(\sin^2x+\cos^2x)^2-2\sin^2x\cos^2x}=\frac{\tfrac12\sin 2x}{1-\frac12\sin^22x}\\&=\frac{\sin 2x}{2-\sin^22x}=\frac{\sin 2x}{1+\cos^22x}.
\end{align}

Next use substitution: set $\;u=\cos 2x$, $\;\mathrm d u=-2\sin 2x\,\mathrm d x$.

Comment: nice solution :-) +1 I like it.

Comment: @Math-fun: Thanks for your kind appreciation. It seems great minds think together ;o)

Comment: I enjoyed it and in fact typed it but then deleted upon seeing yours :-)

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

$$\dfrac{\sin x\cos x}{\sin^4x+\cos^4x}=\dfrac{\tan x\sec^2x}{\tan^4x+1}$$

Set $\tan^2x=y$

OR $$\dfrac{\sin x\cos x}{\sin^4x+\cos^4x}=\dfrac{\cot x\csc^2x}{\cot^4x+1}$$

Set $\cot^2x=u$

Answer (score 2):

If you want to continue your solution, then with substitution $t^2=u$
$$I=\int_0^1\dfrac{t}{2t^4-2t^2+1}dt=\dfrac12\int_0^1\dfrac{1}{2u^2-2u+1}du=\int_0^1\dfrac{1}{(2u-1)^2+1}du$$
and then with substitution $2u-1=w$
$$I=\dfrac12\int_{-1}^1\dfrac{1}{w^2+1}dw=\color{blue}{\dfrac{\pi}{4}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Letting $u=\tan x$, one has
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sin(x)\cos(x)}{\sin^4(x)+\cos^4(x)}dx\\
&=&\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\tan(x)\sec^2(x)}{\tan^4(x)+1}dx\\
&=&\int_0^\infty\frac{u}{u^4+1}du\\
&=&\frac12\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{u^2+1}du\\
&=&\frac12\arctan（u)\bigg|_0^\infty\\
&=&\frac\pi4.
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 0):

Perform the change of variable $y=\sin^2 x$,

$\begin{align}J&=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sin(x)\cos(x)}{\sin^4(x)+\cos^4(x)}dx\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x^2+(1-x)^2}\,dx\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \frac{1}{2x^2-2x+1}\,dx\\
&=\int_0^1 \frac{1}{(2x-1)^2+1}\,dx\\
\end{align}$

Perform the change of variable $y=2x-1$,

$\begin{align}
J&=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^1 \frac{1}{x^2+1}\,dx\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\Big[\arctan x\Big]_{-1}^1\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\times\frac{\pi}{2}\\
&=\boxed{\frac{\pi}{4}}
\end{align}$